# Bug on last element of nav-tabs with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a bug with Bootstrap's nav-tabs.
When I click on the 2 last nav of a line, there is a bug that displays the nav-tab in the wrong order...

Visual rendering example:

[image]

My code look-like this: [Test Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FC02JVTB4JNI)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can actually see in the screenshot, the problem lies in the fact that active tab is about `2px` lower than the rest. To fix, increase the top negative `margin`:

```
ul.bar_tabs>li.active {
    margin-top: -17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this style on your custom CSS file.

```
ul.bar_tabs>li.active {
  border-right: 0px solid #D3D6DA;
}
```

I think it will fine.